# How to update a list inside a elif clause and return the list

Tags: python, list, append

How do i write a python code so that my list of numbers can be updated within an elif cause?
I start off with an empty an empty list then from there i have to ask the user how many new scores they want to add to the list then add those numbers to the list.Then i have to go back to the menu system and ask the user to press 3 if they want the average of those number in the list. here my code below the problem im having is that the scores are being updated in the elif clause but once i get out the clause the list goes back to being empty. please help!

Comment: <assuming homework> Has your professor/instructor talked to you about scope of variables and variable passing, it seems these two things would clean up your code and the problem fairly quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Move the statement that binds an empty list to before the loop.

```
scores = []
while 1:
   ...
```

Comment: i tried that but when i tried to call avgScores() i still got an error that said, "s += scores[index] 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'list'"

Comment: Thats probably because you are appending a list onto your scores list. `scores.append(addScores())` appends the return value of `addScores()` to your scores list. It looks like `addScores()` returns a list. This ends up making `scores` a list of lists, ex: `[[3,4],[7,5],[3,4]]`

Answer (score 0):

Your addScores method looks like it's returning a list, the append method is for a single element, use extend instead of append in your elif statement.

As well, your addScores method isn't instantiating a local scores list to append to, so it's going to return an empty list since one is never instantiated.  Either pass your list you want to modify to it, or have a local list that it returns, currently you're doing neither.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, functions shouldn't be defined in a while loop; define them outside the loop and pass in arguments. A clean way of keeping track of the scores list would be to use a global variable, so that every function in your program can access it.

Your modified code could look like:

```
scores = []

def addScores():
    enteredScores = []
    while True:
        numOfScores = input("How many new scores would you like to add: ")
        try:
            if int(numOfScores) > 0:
                for i in range(int(numOfScores)):
                    newInput = input("Please enter a score: ")
                    enteredScores.append(newInput)
                print(enteredScores)
                return enteredScores
            else:
                print("Please enter a positive integer.")
                continue
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a positive integer.")

while True:
    print("0 - Clear scores")
    print("1 - Input more scores")
    print("2 - Print scores")
    print("3 - Average scores")
    option = input("Please choose an option: ")

    if option == 0:
        scores = []
    elif option == 1:
        scores += addScores()
    elif option == 2:
        print("Scores:", scores)
    elif option == 3:
        try:
            avgScore = sum(scores)/len(scores)
            print("Average:", avgScore)
        except TypeError:
            print("Invalid score contained in list.")
    else:
        print("Quitting current program.")
        break
    replay = input("Do you wish to continue? (Y/N)")
    replay = replay.lower()
    if replay == "y" or replay == "yes":
        continue
    else:
        break

print("Goodbye!")
```

I added two try/except statements. If an error is raised in a program, and it fits one of the mentioned types (ValueError and TypeError), instead of shutting down the program, it handles the error with the except statement. If you haven't covered those, you can remove them and the program should work fine. I also cleaned up the logic a bit - originally, your replay variable didn't do anything, so by moving it into the loop, it now either continues or breaks the program.

Comment: Why a global variable? you can simply pass it as function argument.
Also the first line is not useful at all. The global statement is meant to declare that a variable _inside a function_ is global.

Comment: I think global syntax is a little cleaner, but it could go either way. Thanks for the note about the first line, I'll take that out now.

Comment: Globals are terrible and pretty much should never be used, it's bad code practice and leads to vulnerable and less maintainable code.  It's python's version of the Goto statement.  If you want "globals" you should use a class and init with self.

Comment: Ok, removed all the globals, now the addScores just returns a list which is added on to the original.